# Merge table of linked table contains value sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge

I need to merge a as seen below, but I only want to do this if the table dbo.Problem has the value 1 in the IsValid column. dbo.Problem is linked to dbo.delivery by dbo.Problem.ID = dbo.Delivery.IssueID.

---

```
merge [dbo].[Delivery] as D 
using [ReportSvr].[Report].[dbo].[Delivery] as LinkD

on ( D.[ID] = LinkD.[ID])
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT(
        [ID]
        ,[IssueID]
        ,[column2]
        ,[column3]
    )
    VALUES(
        [ID]
        ,[IssueID]
        ,[column]
        ,[column]
    );
GO
```

---

Is tried something like;

```
select d.IssueID, i.IsValid 
From Delivery d
left join (Select* From Issue where IsValid = 1) i
on d.IssueID = i.ID
```

since first step must be to be able to the wanted rows.

**Output:**

```
IssueID IsValid
1       1
2       NULL
6       NULL
7       1
8       1
9       1
10      NULL
```

As you see I failed terribly....

I'm new (second day) to SQL, sorry if this is an easy task I should know about.

I hope you are able to help me.

Comment: If you are not using MySQL then you should remove that tag.

Comment: You have used/Mentioned different tables in your question and then the `Merge` and then the `select statements`? What tables are you really working with also what exactly are you trying to do? `[dbo].[Delivery]` , `[ReportSvr].[Report].[dbo].[Delivery]` , `dbo.Issue`.  Also where is the column `IsValid` in `dbo.Problem` or in `dbo.Issue`

Comment: Sorry if I haven't been clear.
I have to merge two tables, as shown i the first snip, but i only want to merge row from [ReportSvr].[Report].[dbo].[Delivery] where the value IsValid = 1 in [ReportSvr].[Report].[dbo].[Issue] the two tables are linked by [Delivery].[IssueID] = [Issue].[ID].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an INNER JOIN will only show deliveries that have a matching record in the Issue table. An INNER JOIN will only show records where there's a match on the join field. In your attempt you're using a LEFT JOIN which will show everything in the left table, [Delivery] ("left" makes sense if you show the entire query on a single line) and matching records in the right table, [Issue].

```
SELECT d.IssueID, i.IsValid 
FROM Delivery d
    INNER JOIN Issue i
        ON d.IssueID = i.ID
WHERE i.IsValid = 1
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation as to why your solution should work?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you're new to this. You must have copied the query somewhere with the left join. You can get lost when you start learning join types, but honestly 99% of my queries are INNER or LEFT joins, so once you get those down you'll go a long way. Also, if it just says "JOIN" without a modifier, it's an INNER join by default, at least in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks now that part work :)
How do I apply that snip of  code into the merge, so that only Deliveries with the value IsValid = 1 in the linked Issue table get merged?

Comment: The WHERE clause is already taking care of that for you, but I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the MERGE. Merge is best used when you're trying to match up two tables on many different fields with complex logic. This seems like a simple INSERT INTO - are you trying to put the merged values into a new table?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me out, I managed to solved the problem with the help from Russell Fox. I just wanted to post the answer.

---

```
merge [dbo].[Delivery] as D 

using(
  select d.*, i.IsValid 
  From [ErrorReportSvr].[ErrorReport].[dbo].[Delivery] d
  inner join (Select* From [ErrorReportSvr].[ErrorReport].[dbo].[Issue]    where IsValid = 1) i
  on d.IssueID = i.ID
) as LinkD

on ( D.[ID] = LinkD.[ID])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT(
    [ID]
    ,[IssueID]
    ,[column2]
    ,[column3]
)
VALUES(
    [ID]
    ,[IssueID]
    ,[column2]
    ,[column3]
);
GO
```

---